# What is a good tutorial on the QuickTime API for MS Windows?

Tags: python, windows, quicktime, rebol

I'm working on a project that has to read and manipulate QuickTimes on Windows. Unfortunately, all the tutorials and sample code at the Apple site seem to be pretty much Mac specific. Is there a good resource on the web that deals specifically with programming QuickTime for Windows? Yes, I know that I can bludgeon my way (eventually) through the Mac stuff and eventually get something to work, but I would really like to see a treatment of the cleanest and best way to deal with it on Windows and what gotcha's to beware.

For extra points, it would be cool to see how someone might use the QuickTime API from a dynamic language like REBOL or Python (no, the Mac Python QuickTime bindings don't count!).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QuickTime For Windows](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Rm/QTforWindows/QTforWindows/B-Chapter/2QuickTimeForWindows.html) starts off with the differences between Mac OS and Windows programming and [Building QuickTime Capability Into a Windows Application](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Rm/QTforWindows/QTforWindows/C-Chapter/3BuildingQuickTimeCa.html) then discusses how to incorporate the capability into Windows platform

Answer (score 1):

There is an official mailing list for [QT developers](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/quicktime-api). It has an archive. It would certainly be worth subscribing to it if you are seriously trying to *use* QT for something, especially if it is the slightest bit off the beaten path.

IMHO, the official docs are more than a little too Apple-centric. Note that the Windows book assumes you already have experience with QT on Macs. At the time I was looking (about a year ago), I had a mandate to deal with QT from .NET, either from C# or managed C++. That was not a well documented way of doing things then.

There is a body of sample code for Windows somewhere at the Apple developer site, which might help if you can find it. I seem to have lost the links I had at one time. Just knowing it does (or did a year ago) exist might be enough to nudge you in the right direction.

Almost all of the sample code available is ordinary C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a Google code project with my QuickTime for Windows code at [code.google.com/p/qtip](http://code.google.com/p/qtip). The idea is to structure things in a semi-tutorial fashion (as I learn this stuff myself!) so that others can learn from my pain...